# Get and save value had been add from dropdownlist to database

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Here is my dropdownlist:

```
<div id="addCam"></div>
<div id="addDiv">
    <select id="type1">
            <option value="">- Kiểu áo -</option>
            @foreach (var item in Model.teetypes)
            {
            <option value="@item.Image">@item.Name</option>
        }
    </select>
    <a class="btn btn-info btn-default" id="addBtnH" style="text-align:center" title="Thêm sản phẩm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
</div>
Button submit:
<input type="submit" value="Khởi động chiến dịch" onclick="return validate()" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" />
```

Javascript .append():

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 2;
    var maxAppend = 0;
    $("#addBtnH").click(function () {
            var name = $("#type1 option:selected").val();
            var name1 = $("#type1 option:selected").text();
            if (name == '') return;
            if (maxAppend >= 5) {
                $("#addDiv").hide();
                return;
            }
            $("#addDiv").show();
            $("#addCam").append("<div class='widget' id='del" + count + "'><div class='widget-body'><div class='col-md-3'><span style='display:block'><img src='/Content/assets/img/avatars/" + name + ".png' title='"+name+"' id='tee" + count + "' height='75'/></span></div>" +
                "<div class='col-md-1'><select id='color" + count + "' onchange='changeColor" + count + "()'>@foreach (var item in Model.teecolors){<option value='@item.Color' style='background-color: #@item.Color'></option>}</select></div><div id='dis" + count + "'>" + name1 + "</div><input type='hidden' id='diss" + count + "'>" + name1 + "</div>" +
                "<hr class='wide'><input type='text' name='input'><a class='btn btn-info btn-default' rel='"+name+"' id='delete" + count + "' style='text-align:center' title='Xóa sản phẩm'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a>" +
                "<script>$('#delete" + count + "').click(function(){var rel = $('#tee"+count+"').attr('title'); $('#type1 option[value = '+rel.toString()+']').unwrap();$('#del" + count + "').remove();});" + "<" + "/script>" +
                "<script type='text/javascript'>function changeColor" + count + "(){var eID = document.getElementById('color" + count + "'); var colorVal = eID.options[eID.selectedIndex].value; document.getElementById('tee" + count + "').style.background = '#' + colorVal;}" + "<" + "/script>" +
                "</div></div>");
        count = count + 1;
        maxAppend++;
        $("#type1 option:selected").wrap('<span/>');
        $("#type1").val('');
    });
});
```

I have name and name1 for get value and text of dropdown from db to display in .append() when click button add. With this code, could I save all value option had been added to new table in database? how to do that in controller? Or I have to rewrite the javascript .append()?

My controller name is CreateCampaign.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Append it to some form and then serilize.  For example:

```
<form id="myForm">
...
</form>
$('btn').click(function(){
$('#myForm').append(...)
});
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(){
$.post(url, $( this ).serialize() ...
});
```

In Controller you shoud have array or list something like this :

```
string [] name1
```

or use FormCollection